# How to provide credentials and other secrets in Google App Engine?

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a webapp, with all my configurations defined in a file which includes, passwords, secrets and other configs. What is a secure and easy way to provide these settings when deploying to App Engine?
I have 2 files: config.dev.yaml and config.prod.yaml.

Solutions that I found:

- google cloud key manager (GKM) however i think this solution seems expensive, and complex to implement.
- put secrets in app.yaml as environment variables. A lot of people said that this is not secure?
- include config file in deployment with source code. also people say this is a bad idea.

solution I'm thinking about that I'm not sure if it will work:
store all my config in the Firestore, and pull them at a build time?

I spent all day looking for answer to this, nobody seems to have a "standard" simple solution.

Comment: Did you mean to say "pull them at run time" instead of "pull them at build time"?

Comment: @MuffinTop I probably need them at runtime. I have passwords and other credentials to access third party services, so I think run time is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Secrets need to be kept secret. Therefore, putting the secrets in plain text either in environment variable or in a config file is not a good idea. And in both case, you will commit the files in the repositories, which is also ugly.

So, you need to keep the secrets secret until you need to use them.

- You can use [KMS](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs) and manage yourself your encryption/decryption. But it's not very funny to do and there is a lot of extra code to implement. At the end, you store only encrypted version of your secret
- You can use [Secret manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs). You store only a secret reference and a simple API call allows you to get the secrets. And you store only the secret manager references in your files.

The main issue with these secure solutions is if you have framework or library that autoload values from configuration automatically. Therefore, you have to implement a hook at the application startup to convert the values from secret form to plain text, and then continue the normal loading.

If you share your language, I could have answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe after extensive search, going with "Secret Manager" is the way to go. My app is written in Go, and just have one config.yaml file that contains passwords/secrets and other credentials to access third party APIs. I couldn't find good resources that discuss this issue in Go related forums :(

Comment: Do you need guidance to use Secret Manager in Go?

Comment: I haven't tried to code it yet, I've read the docs and seems pretty straight forward. Seems like there are multiple ways to do it. one with gRPC call, another with REST, and third is go library where you build protobuf and it handles making rpc call for you. I'm not very proficient when it comes to rpc and protobufs, do you  suggest I take REST route?

Comment: Choose either the REST API or the Client library. Client Library generate RPC call, more network efficient. All depends if  you need performances or not really.